# Hide login view if user logged in

Tags: ios, objective-c

i'm try to never show user login view if he logged in 
i do this in viewWillAppear

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"userName"]) {

        NSDictionary *d = [defaults objectForKey:@"currentUser"];
        UserProfile *userData = [[UserProfile alloc]initWithDictionary:d];
        [[NetworkModel sharedManager] setCurrentUser:hh];
        [self loginResults];
    }

    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;

}
```

and loginResults function

```
   -(void)childrenReceived:(NSNotification *) notification
    {
        [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
        NSDictionary *userInfo = notification.userInfo;
        NSArray *allKids = [userInfo objectForKey:@"children"];
        RootViewController *sideBarRoot= [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"root"];
        sideBarRoot.children = allKids;
         [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
        [self presentViewController:sideBarRoot animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: what you want to do ? please edit you question to provide more information and read [How to ask question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: check this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41864151/how-to-present-login-screen-only-when-a-userdefaults-key-doesnt-exist/41864888#41864888

Comment: And the question is..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the below coding

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
-(void) didFinishLogin
    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
    CCKFNavDrawer*homeNavController = (CCKFNavDrawer*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NavigationLoginID"];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    self.window.rootViewController = homeNavController;

-(void)didFinishLogout

    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
    UINavigationController *homeNavController = (UINavigationController*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginNavigationID"];
    LoginVC *objloginVC = (LoginVC*)[homeNavController topViewController];
    objloginVC.delegate=self;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    self.window.rootViewController = homeNavController;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
      if( [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectforkey:@"loginKey"]isequaltostring:@""])
        [self didFinishLogout];

       else
        [self didFinishLogin];
```